# dropdown getting overwritten after upgrading bootstrap version to 4.6.1 from 4.3.1

Tags: html, css, angularjs, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

Earlier, my bootstrap version in my angular project was ~4.3.1. When i upgraded the bootstrap version to 4.6.1, the dropdown is not working correctly. As you can see in the image, that it is getting overlapped with the below text but it was working fine before the bootstrap upgrade.

[image]
HTML file

```
<rca-modal-layout (close)="bsModalRef.hide()" class="overflow-fix">
        <ng-container modal-title>Assign to</ng-container>
        <ng-container modal-body>
            <span class="case-text">Case Selected: {{ selectedCases?.length }}</span>
            <div class="rca-forms rca-custom-control custom-radio assign-self">
                <input
                    data-selector="radio-btn"
                    type="radio"
                    id="assignSelf"
                    name="assignRadio"
                    class="custom-control-input"
                    (click)="radioPressed(assignEnum.self)"
                    [(ngModel)]="selectedRadio"
                    [value]="assignEnum.self"
                    [disabled]="disableSelfAssignRadio"
                />
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="assignSelf">Assign to me </label>
            </div>

            <div class="rca-forms rca-custom-control custom-radio assign-others">
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    id="assignOthers"
                    name="assignRadio"
                    class="custom-control-input"
                    (click)="radioPressed(assignEnum.others)"
                    [(ngModel)]="selectedRadio"
                    [value]="assignEnum.others"
                    [checked]="selectedOtherUserName != null"
                    [disabled]="disableAssignOtherRadio"
                />
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="assignOthers">Assign to user</label>
                <rca-select
                    [data]="assigneeList"
                    (selectChanged)="onOtherUserValueChanges($event)"
                    [selectedValues]="selectedOtherUser"
                    [settings]="selectSettings"
                    placeholder="Select user"
                    data-selector="assignee-list-dropdown"
                >
                </rca-select>
            </div>

            <div class="rca-forms rca-custom-control custom-radio assign-others">
                <input
                    data-selector="radio-btn"
                    type="radio"
                    id="unassignMe"
                    name="unassignRadio"
                    class="custom-control-input"
                    (click)="radioPressed(assignEnum.unAssign)"
                    [(ngModel)]="selectedRadio"
                    [value]="assignEnum.unAssign"
                    [disabled]="disableUnAssignRadio"
                />
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="unassignMe"
                    >Un-assign (Case will not be assigned to any user)</label
                >
            </div>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container modal-footer>
            <div class="float-right mr-2">
                <rca-button
                    class="mr-2"
                    data-selector="submit-btn"
                    [disabled]="selectedRadio === 0 || (selectedRadio === 2 && selectedOtherUserName === null)"
                    [label]="'Submit'"
                    [minWidth]="'75px'"
                    [isLoading]="submissionInProgress"
                    (click)="submitButtonClicked()"
                >
                </rca-button>
                <button data-selector="cancel-btn" class="btn btn-secondary pl-2 pr-2 mr-2" (click)="bsModalRef.hide()">
                    Cancel
                </button>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </rca-modal-layout>
```

CSS file

```
.case-text {
    display: block;
    color: $mid-grey-d40;
}

.assign-button {
    margin: 12px 0;
}

.custom-control-label {
    padding-top: 4px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 13px;
}

.assign-self {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.assign-others {
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.custom-radio {
    ::ng-deep {
        rca-select {
            margin-left: 12px;
            .dropdown-menu {
                width: 250px;
            }
            .form-control {
                width: 100px;
            }
            .search-group {
                height: 32px;
            }
            .dropdown-action-button {
                display: none;
            }
        }
    }
}

.overflow-fix {
    ::ng-deep .modal-body {
        overflow-x: initial !important;
        overflow-y: initial !important;
    }
}

.btn-secondary {
    width: 73px;
}
```

The classes and elements starting from "rca" are from a external common repo containing common ui components and classes.

```
custom-control, .rca-custom-control {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    min-height: 1.275rem;
    padding-left: 1.625rem;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    color-adjust: exact;
}
dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 10rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    margin: 0.125rem 0 0;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.custom-control, .rca-custom-control {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    min-height: 1.275rem;
    padding-left: 1.625rem;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    color-adjust: exact;
}
```